# WMIC OS get numberofusers return different results on different PCs

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, wmic

I am responsible for a number of PCs that have been installed with all the same software and base load. I have recently added another PC to the list and it reports 1 more user on-line than the other PCs. If I try 'query session' I get the same results. I could get the number of user by counting the number that are either active or disconnected from the query server results, but using the wmic call should return the same answer. This is usually 1 more then the number of users as it counts the services as 1. This particular PC shows 1 more than the others e.g it returns 3 when one person is logged on.

Is there a setting that I can change to resolve this?

**wmic call:**

```
echo &wmic /failfast:on /node:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX os get NumberOfUsers /format:textvaluelist.xsl>>"C:\Status.csv"
```

**from query session:**
C:\Users\user111>query session

> SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE
>   DEVICE
>
> services                                    0  Disc
>
> console           user111                  1  Active
>
> rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen

This normally return 2 for the number of users.

**---------**

Why is one PC reporting 1 extra from numberofusers wmic call?
Thanks...

Comment: flagged as should be moved to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Some quick testing shows that the listening session seems to only be present if Remote Desktop access is enabled, which makes sense.  So probably the new machine is the only one with Remote Desktop access enabled.  (The "allow remote access to your computer" setting.)